# To use utf8 or not - MySQL and PHP character encoding issue

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

I have a string stored in MySQL like this: `ï»¿ÛŒÚ©ÛŒ Ø§Ø² Ø` where my table's character set is `utf8` and collation is `utf8_general_ci`.

When I retrieve the string from MySQL, the browser shows it like this: `یکی از بهترین راه` and it's ok (It is persian).

Note:

- I used `mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8_persian_ci'");` after connecting
  to MySQL.
- I put `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type"
  content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />` tag in head of each page.

Now, I need use `mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");`.

But after using it, the browser shows that string like this: `ï»¿ÛŒÚ©ÛŒ Ø§Ø² Ø` (as same as stored in MySQL).

How can I change my MySQL stored records and  solve my problem? Or use some PHP code to convert the output encoding?

Comment: I didn't test it, but [utf8_encode()](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.utf8-encode.php) may help you

Comment: @romainberger - What does ISO-8859-1 have to do with this?

Comment: @romainberger: I used your suggestion to convert retrieved string from MySQL and then passed it to HTML. But It shows another weird text.

Comment: Please, check collation of DB, tables and columns involved in your query. It must be utf8_persian_ci for best results

Comment: Please note that the `mysql_query()` function is deprecated (along with other `mysql_xx()` functions). It is obsolete and insecure. You should consider switching to either the `mysqli_xxx()` funcs or the PDO library. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that your `SET NAMES 'utf8_persian_ci'` command was *invalid* (utf8_persion_ci is a *collation*, not an *encoding*).  If you run it in a terminal you will see an error `Unknown character set: 'utf8_persian_ci'`. Thus your application, when it *stored* the data, was using the `latin1` character set.  MySQL interpreted your input as latin1 characters which it then stored encoded as utf-8.  Likewise when the data was pulled back out, MySQL converted it from UTF-8 back to latin1 and (hopefully, most of the time) the original bytes you gave it.

In other words, all your data in the database is completely messed up, but it just so happened to work.

To fix this, you need to undo what you did. The most straightforward way is using PHP:

1. `SET NAMES latin1;`
2. Select every single text field from every table.
3. `SET NAMES utf8;`
4. Update the same rows using the same string unaltered.

Alternatively you can perform these steps inside MySQL, but it's tricky because MySQL understands the data to be in a certain character set.  You need to modify your text columns to a BLOB type, then modify them *back* to text types with a utf8 character set. See the section at the bottom of the [`ALTER TABLE` MySQL documentation labeled "Warning" in red](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html).

After you do either one of these things, the bytes stored in your database columns will be the actual character set they claim to be. Then, *make sure you always use [`mysql_set_charset('utf8')`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php)* on any database access from PHP that you may do in the future! Otherwise you will mess things up again.  (Note, *do not use a simple `mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8')`!* There are corner cases (such as a reset connection) where this can be reset to `latin1` without your knowledge. `mysql_set_charset()` will set the charset whenever necessary.)

It would be best if you switched away from `mysql_*` functions and used `PDO` instead with the `charset=utf8` parameter in your [PDO dsn](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php).

Comment: The MySQL documentation I linked to goes into detail. Essentially, `ALTER TABLE mytable MODIFY mycolumn BLOB` then `ALTER TABLE mytable MODIFY mycolumn [original-type] CHARACTER SET utf8`.

Answer (score 1):

Probably what you need is to change the column Charset and Collation.

Try executing this query:

```
ALTER TABLE  `YOUR_TABLE_NAME` CHANGE  `YOUR_COLUMN_NAME`  `YOUR_COLUMN_NAME` VARCHAR( 255 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL
```

(In the example I assumed VARCHAR with a DEFAULT NULL VALUE)

If this works for you then you could insert in your my.conf file the code below to make utf8  the default charset:

```
default-character-set   = utf8
```

Comment: My table character set and collation is currently `utf8` and `utf8_general_ci`. Do you mean I should re-convert them?

Comment: Did you inert your data with this charset or with another one? I experienced this kind of problem in java and I had to reinsert all the data using the same charset on all the part involved in communication i.e. client, server and mysql.

Answer (score 1):

Possible solutions:

1. Add "AddDefaultCharset UTF-8" to your site's .htaccess file.
2. Add header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); to the top of your PHP file.
3. Use utf8_encode() php function on the data that needs to be displayed in Persian.