# How to search with non utf chars in mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql

I need to search from table, like

`select * from geo where state='Grästorp'`

But it does not give me any results. but when I run this query with phpmyadmin it gives me right result. How to search with in MySQL with non utf-8  chars?

Comment: this may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14256742/to-use-utf8-or-not-mysql-and-php-character-encoding-issue

Answer (score 0):

select * from geo where state LIKE '%Grästorp%' collate utf8_bin;

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
SET NAMES 'utf8'
```

before querying anything else that has to do with unicode.