# How to show with france language in searching

Tags: php, sql, unicode, utf-8

I have problem France language in searching in php . My project work fine in English, but when I search  in France language, it always shows `Message: non-utf8 string: é`. Any one have solution with this problem? Help me please.

Comment: Provide some code? Is it web app, desktop app?

Comment: yes i using php in zendframwork

Comment: You need to check your db character settings. For detail refer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14256742/to-use-utf8-or-not-mysql-and-php-character-encoding-issue

Answer (score 2):

you can use function `htmlentities`

example : htmlentities($testForSearch);

more you can see here http://php.net/htmlentities

Comment: i don't know why this function can help for a case in a function but other function still can't help